# Fully prove that curve is of certain type

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

I apologize for the generic title. By type I mean that it belongs to a class of curves, such as helixes, circles, lines, etc.

To the point however, I stumbled into an exercise where asked to describe which type of curve that has the following parameterization:

$$\vec{r} = (a \cos t \sin t)\hat{i} + (a \sin^2 t)\hat{j} + bt\hat{k}, $$

What I did was that I tried to express the $x$- and $y$-components in the form $C_1 \sin f(t)$ and $C_2 \cos f(t)$ respectively. So:

$$x=a \cos t \sin t=\frac{a}{2} \sin 2t$$
$$y = a \sin^2 t=a\frac{1-\cos^2 2t}{2} \iff 2y - a = -a\cos 2t$$

Using this, I confirmed that:
$$x^2 + \left(y - \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 = \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)
^2$$

This implies that the curve lies on the cylinder with the above equation. However, this is where I get a bit confused as to how to proceed. It is seemingly clear that the equation represents a helix, considering that $z$ is increasing and both $x$ and $y$ draws out projections that are circles in the $xy$-plane. But how do I actually prove this? Technically, it could be the line $x = y = 0$ as well, if I don't proceed to somehow that $x$ and $y$ are "behaving circular" (you get what I mean, hopefully). Worth mentioning is that the book doesn't seem to prove this either.

**Question:** Can I in this particular case prove that the curve is a helix? My initial guess was that it had to do with $x,y \in C^0$, along with some other constraint, but I can't really get any further.

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=2t-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{a}{2} \sin 2t \\
  \dfrac{a}{2}-\dfrac{a}{2} \cos 2t \\
  bt
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\ \dfrac{a}{2} \\ \dfrac{b\pi}{4}
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{a}{2} \cos u \\
  \dfrac{a}{2} \sin u \\
  \dfrac{bu}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is a helix with axis $(x,y,z)=\left( 0, \dfrac{a}{2}, z \right)$, curvature $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and torsion $\dfrac{2b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: I can't believe how I didn't think about how there may be an equation for a helix, rather than going on about continuity. So just to clarify, it's enough to just refer to that equation then? Of course, with the steps that you showed, to be clear.

Comment: I think so, it's just a translated one.